# Network Stream object disposed when trying to re-write in a re-opened connection

Tags: c#, stream

Everything is going fine with connection , except when i close the connection and reopen (everything fine till now , data is received fine).
The error pops up when I try to write in the stream :
Cannot access a disposed object: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream' !! 
I have tried using a new instance of client each time I connect 
When closing connection : i have tried all these things like `_client.GetStream().Close();
_client.Close();`

but everything fail

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myform = this;
    }
    public static Form1 myform;
    Client c1;
    public void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        c1 = new Client();
        try
        {  c1.Connect(IPADRESStext.Text, PORTNUMBERtext.Text);    }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }

    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c1.Disconnect(); 
    }
}

public sealed partial class Client 
{
    public void SendData(byte[] data)
    {            _sender.SendData(data);       }

    public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;

    public void Connect(string IPADRESStxt, string PORTNUMBERtxt)
    {
        sq = new sequence();

        _client = new TcpClient(IPADRESStxt, Int32.Parse(PORTNUMBERtxt));

        _stream = _client.GetStream();
        _sender = new Sender(_stream);
        _receiver = new Receiver(_stream);       
        _receiver.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;
    }
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        _stream.Close();
        _client.Close();

        //_client.Client.Disconnect(false);

        //tcpClient.GetStream().Close();
        //tcpClient.Close();
    }

    private void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = DataReceived;
        if (handler != null) DataReceived(this, e);  // re-raise event
    }

    private TcpClient _client;
    private  NetworkStream _stream;

    private Receiver _receiver;
    private Sender _sender;
```

}

```
public sealed partial class Client
{
    private sealed class Sender
    {
        internal void SendData(byte[] data)
        {
             _stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);    /// 2 When trying to execute this instruction      
        }
        internal Sender(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            _thread = new Thread(Run);
            _thread.Start();
        }

        private void Run()
        {  
            // Code Code Code 
            SendData(Sframe);    ///   1 Error pops up here
        }
        private NetworkStream _stream;
        private Thread _thread;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the stream object from before you closed and reopened or after?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I didn't understand what you mean ?

Comment: Did you open the connection, obtain the stream object, close the connection, reopen it, then try to use the stream object from before? Or did you obtain a new stream object after reopening it?

Comment: Iam making a new instance of client (as code says) each time I connect , which means iam using a new stream object

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen when using a new instance of client class each time i connect : doesn't that instantiate a new private stream ?

Comment: It should, hence why I stopped commenting, I have no further input which would be of help.