# How can i use a new stream after closing connection without restarting application

Tags: c#, tcp, stream

I have a C# application that allows user to : open connection / Do things .. / Close Connection In a windows form .
Problem : When close connection and open again (without restarting app) , I have this erroe : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
When trying to SendData , The stream is disposed and can never be used again . What is the best way to use a new stream without restarting the app.

Code is here[C# stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747057/network-stream-object-disposed-when-trying-to-re-write-in-a-re-opened-connection)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network Stream object disposed when trying to re-write in a re-opened connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37747057/network-stream-object-disposed-when-trying-to-re-write-in-a-re-opened-connection)

Comment: So go through this article, and use it's advice to improve the question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close(v=vs.110).aspx). Closing a stream will also Dispose them; you have to create a new one.